# Caffe - draw_net_to_file - 'Classifier' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I found the `draw_net_to_file` method in [`draw.py`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/draw.py) and want to use it to understand the Caffe network I was given to work with better.

The problem is that the following code

```
import caffe
from caffe.draw import draw_net_to_file
import numpy as np

weights = 'reference_model/caffe_reference_imagenet_model.weights'
means = 'reference_model/ilsvrc_2012_mean_reshaped.npy'
model = 'reference_model/imagenet_model_deploy.prototxt'

npmeans = np.load(means)

cls = caffe.Classifier(
    model,
    weights,
    mean=npmeans,
    image_dims=(256, 256),
    channel_swap=(2,1,0),
    raw_scale=(255),
)

draw_net_to_file(cls, "drawn_net.png");
print "DONE"
```

fails with the following error

```
/caffe/python/caffe/draw.pyc in get_pydot_graph(caffe_net, rankdir, label_edges)
--> 105   pydot_graph = pydot.Dot(caffe_net.name, graph_type='digraph', rankdir=rankdir)
AttributeError: 'Classifier' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Upon closer investigation, the `Classifier` object really does not expose many methods of the underlying `Net` object, such as `name`. How do I instantiate a correctly working `Net` instance for this case?

I'm using Caffe built from revision `737ea5e936821b5c69f9c3952d72693ae5843370`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the script [`draw_net.py`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/draw_net.py) where you can see an example of how to use the functions of `draw.py`. The `net` argument is not exactly the same as the `caffe.Net` object but rather a parsed prototxt:

```
from google.protobuf import text_format
import caffe.draw
from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2

net = caffe_pb2.NetParameter()
text_format.Merge(open(args.input_net_proto_file).read(), net)
```